# jvectormap uncaught typeerror

Tags: jquery, typeerror, jvectormap

I have been trying to get this plugin working for hours and can't seem to do so. I am fairly new to jquery so i do apologize if i say something stupid :) I tried following the tutorial provided on the site but have had no luck. Anyways my code so far is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> vectormap </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/jquery-mousewheel.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jvectormap.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/map.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-jvectormap-au-mill-en.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
   <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#map').vectorMap({map: 'au_mill_en'});
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The errors im getting are:
1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined 
2. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Appreciate any help as this is doing my head in !!

cheers

ps sorry for not indenting properly

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jquery library before including any of your plugins library. so put below line as first library include -

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

like below

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<title> vectormap </title>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/jquery-jvectormap.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" />
<!-- must be the first library to include as this is prerequisite for other plugins . lib-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-jvectormap-au-mill-en.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-jvectormap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jvectormap.js"></script> 
<script src="js/map.js"></script> -->
</head>
```

Comment: your solution has fixed the initial problem and i have updated my code but now i get two different errors
1.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined 
2.Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
my only guess is that i am missing a .js file

Comment: for first problem, you need to see API documents for the plugins you are using and for second error comes when you find some element using `id` or `class` or any other jquery selector but it is not getting.